# Read and write value in xml based on attribute

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file as below and I want to read data from my device and write the data into "value" column by using python script.

```
<TopoDefs>
  <Device Name="SNB" LogicalType="CORE" 
          IdCode="0x03886A21" Mask="0xf0000000">
    <Variable name="A0" value="0x52001321" type="GREEN" /> 
    <Variable name="A1" value="0x51001321" type="GREEN" /> 
    <Variable name="A2" value="0x03001321" type="GREEN" /> 
    <Variable name="A3" value="0x14001321" type="GREEN" /> 
    <Variable name="B0" value="0x5A001321" type="BLUE" /> 
    <Variable name="B1" value="0x51001321" type="BLUE" /> 
    <Variable name="B2" value="0x04001321" type="BLUE" /> 
    <Variable name="B3" value="0x05001321" type="BLUE" />
  </Device>
</TopoDefs>
```

I am completely a new learner of python scripting. How to parse the xml file and point to the attribute value to replaced by a new value that will changed all the time?
If i using getElementsByTagName and nodevalue, it would read all the string of the node, how do I limit by reading the value only and the other variables remain the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that iterates over all the Devices in the document, and all the Variables in a Device:

```
xmlstr = """<TopoDefs>
  <Device Name="SNB" LogicalType="CORE"
          IdCode="0x03886A21" Mask="0xf0000000">
    <Variable name="A0" value="0x52001321" type="GREEN" />
    <Variable name="A1" value="0x51001321" type="GREEN" />
    <Variable name="A2" value="0x03001321" type="GREEN" />
    <Variable name="A3" value="0x14001321" type="GREEN" />
    <Variable name="B0" value="0x5A001321" type="BLUE" />
    <Variable name="B1" value="0x51001321" type="BLUE" />
    <Variable name="B2" value="0x04001321" type="BLUE" />
    <Variable name="B3" value="0x05001321" type="BLUE" />
  </Device>
</TopoDefs>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
document = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)

for dev in document.iter('Device'):
    for var in dev.iter('Variable'):
        var.set('value', 'new_value')

print ET.tostring(document)
```